# Page duplication on the net - is this commonplace or something serious?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across this (good) question on puzzling.SE:

[My Puzzling Girlfriend](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30309/my-puzzling-girlfriend)

Then I noticed it had a forum-style duplicate here:

http://www.discuzfeed.com/puzzling/lzlzr-my-puzzling-girlfriend.html

I find this very serious(IP theft serious). Is this common or just gone unnoticed till now?

Comment: I just realized there isn't a single link anywhere on the page. No surprise, really.

Comment: Check out this question on the stack exchange meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do . Though this is more along the lines of some random person reposting without giving due credit, i believe that is answered in the question as well. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: I've definitely seen this happen before - some time after a puzzle is posted here, it gets (seemingly robo-)posted on a site with something like "puzzle" in the URL

Comment: Yes, this is just a scrub site (no pun towards the puzzle), made by a scrub.  (Don't believe me?  Click on ANY of the links at the bottom of the page -- about, terms of service, advertising, contact us, help, etc)  .It is designed to pull stuff from legitimate sites, so that it can show up in search engines and make them money from ads, without an ounce of work.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha The good news is, Google is smarter than those guys. It detected a duplicate, and blocked it. Only when I asked to see the latter did it surface.